# ARM PMU read from another core

Tags: arm, cpu, cpu-registers, armv8

I would like to read/write the PMU registers of core0 pmu from core1.
I would like to know if this is possible. I read in the TRM of ARM cortex A53 that these registers are memory mapped. So i assume this is possible. Could someone provide the steps or some implementation steps on how to do this?
Thank you